# Tag <code> reconhecer linguagem (Wordpress)?

Tags: html, wordpress

Não entendo muito dessa tag, mas queria saber como fazer um esquema do estilo desse site em um blog do Wordpress, exemplo de código:

```js
string demo = "StackOverflow";
if(demo.Lenght == 13)
{
    demo += "Brasil";
}
```

Como fazer que ela reconheça as palavras reversadas e as mudem de cores?

Comment: Isso na postagem do wordpress? ou via código mesmo?

Comment: Qualquer um dos dois, sendo html, pois é pra ser publicado no WordPress e ele só lê html.. Tem a tag code, porém ela apenas separa um bloco para o código, não identifica as palavras reversadas de cada língua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for apenas adicionar o highlight na postagem pode escapar o código com `[sourcecode language='nome da linguaguem']`:

```
[sourcecode language='javascript']
  string demo = "StackOverflow";
  if(demo.Lenght == 13){
    demo += "Brasil";
  }
[/sourcecode]
```

É renderizado como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A lista de linguaguens disponíveis e outras configurações estão acessiveis no [manual](https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/)

Comment: Sendo esse um `shortcode` no Wordpress, correto?

Answer (score 2):

Dentro de um site, precisará de algum biblioteca para poder "grifar" ou estilizar seu códio. Nesse aspecto, existe o https://highlightjs.org/, que é uma biblioteca em javascript que pode colorir o seu código-fonte.

Em um exemplo simples, depois de incluir a biblioteca na sua página, poderia utilizá-lo assim para javascript:

```html
<pre>
 <code class="javascript">
  string demo = "StackOverflow";
  if(demo.Lenght == 13)
  {
      demo += "Brasil";
  }
 </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Essa minha resposta se enquadra no sentido geral -- tem vários plugins e shortcodes in WordPress que podem fazer igual.

Comment: @PabloPalácios obrigado pela ajuda no português! :D